# Converting the integer 0000 into a string

Tags: python

For example, I have the code:

```
number = 0000
a = str(number)
print(a)
```

Here, I get the output as 0, instead of 0000, but at the same time, when i take the number as 11111 or so on, this problem doesn't exist. how do i fix this

Comment: There is no number ``0000`` – what you are looking at is a *literal* that evaluates to a number of value ``0``. What exactly are you trying to do? Is the width of numbers known, or do you have to separately handle e.g. "``0000``" and "``00000000``"? Why don't you directly use a string?

Answer (score 1):

Python treats 0000 and 0 as the same number.

```py
print(0000 == 0)
=> True
```

You can't fix this. If you need to represent "0000" you'll have to do it as a string not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in math, left zeros padding are not taken into account for integers so 001 means 1 (001 in Python is SyntaxError though). But you can create strings with left zero padding.

Two options: 1-[format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)  2-[`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

```
number = 0
print(f'{number:>04}')
```

and

```
number = 0
print(str(number).zfill(4))
```

Comment: Note that their other number ``11111`` has 5 digits. It does not look like there is a know, fixed width. Also, left zeros are *only* allowed for zero – ``001`` is a syntax error in Python3.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Right, added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you set the number , 0000 it just means 0
but you can put some 0 in the string varible first and fix it.